# Wordpress: single user account, multiple simultaneous sessions

Tags: wordpress, session, authentication, private

I have looked both here specifically and Google, but I think because the question is similar in wordage to multi-sites, I'm having no luck.

Here's the situation;
I'm developing a site for a client. It's a private site, users not logged in will be directed to the log in page (no problems so far).

Ideally, I'd like everyone be able to log in with a single username and password, mostly because there are potentially a lot of users and who will need access and I don't think they'll go with the idea of giving each person individual log ins (potentially thousands, maybe even tens of thousands of users here).

All these users will be able to do is access the private site; read access only. They won't be editing posts or creating any content.

So I have 3 questions:
1. How many sessions can a single login support? Is there a limit?
2. Is there a plugin or other that supports this? Something that allows this sort of account handling?
3. Will I have to bite the bullet and get details username and password details and import via csv?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would probably be simpler to just use a password protect plugin so anyone who visits your site is prompted for a password.  Then there is no need to worry about using the same user across multiple sessions.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/

Would that work for your situation?

Comment: That could work, although with that plugin files (images etc) would still be accessible if you had the exact url. There's probably something I could do there too though.

Comment: Yes, good point.  If the site is only accessible to family/friends you should probably just hide it from search engines anyhow so that would help.  Very low likliehood of anyone getting direct image URLs I would think, but it is a valid concern.

Comment: Based on this old thread password protecting images isn't possible...even with protected posts or login required.  It is a bit older so this may have changed: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-protect-photos

Comment: The original idea for this site was for it to sit on an intranet but that was not an option for reasons I won't go in to.

Basically, I could just scramble image/file names to make them inaccessible. I am not in anyway bothered about SEO.

Comment: Yea, I think your best bet, and I could certainly be wrong, would be to discourage search engines (which will help images not get indexed) and, as you said, scramble image and files names.  Hope that works for you.